# How to connect INTEX 3.5G (aka 普创E003) Wireless USB modem on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, modem

Can anyone help me out on connecting INTEX 3.5G 7.2 Mbps (aka 普创E003) Wireless USB modem on Ubuntu? Initially it is recognized as a storage device and the `modprobe` command does not create any impact on it. Here are the steps I have followed:

```
tech@tech-Inspiron-N5010:~$ sudo usb_modeswitch -H -v 20a6 -p f00e.

Looking for default devices ….
found matching product ID.
adding device
Found device in default mode, class or configuration (1).
Accessing device 007 on bus 002 ….
Getting the current device configuration ….
OK, got current device configuration (1).
Using first interface: 0×00.
Using endpoints 0×01 (out) and 0×81 (in).
Inquiring device details; driver will be detached ….
Looking for active driver ….
No driver found. Either detached before or never attached.

SCSI inquiry data (for identification).
————————-
Vendor String: Modem.
Model String: Disk.
Revision String: 2.31.
————————-

USB description data (for identification).
————————-
Manufacturer: Modem
Product: Modem Device.
Serial No.: 000000000002.
————————-
Sending Huawei control message ….
OK, Huawei control message sent.
-> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye.

tech@tech-Inspiron-N5010:~$ sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x20a6 product=0xf00e.
```

`usb-devices`:

```
T: Bus=02 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#= 7 Spd=480 MxCh= 0.
D: Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs= 1.
P: Vendor=20a6 ProdID=f00e Rev=00.00.
S: Manufacturer=Modem
S: Product=Modem Device.
S: SerialNumber=000000000002
C: #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA.
I: If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=(none).
```

I have tried this all. I am using the INTEX 3.5G 7.2 Mbps (aka 普创E003) Wireless USB Datacard modem and have tried to configure udev rules and kernel modules too but nothing has worked.
Can anyone tell me what is the real problem?

Comment: Does your modem require any special firmware? If they are proprietary, they aren't installed by default.

Comment: yeah it has a inbuilt driver for windows when once i start it in windows and without unplugging it restarts d pc n boot to ubuntu den it works otherwisw dnt,so vrytym i hav to b4 usin it follow dat procrdure dnt knw whether i can do it dyrctly in linux or not

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this modem does not switch automatically from a USB storage device to a USB Modem. Here is a simple solution.

Download This File [IntexModem](http://www.2shared.com/file/LXTLE23M/IntexModem.html).

Now Extract it and execute the IntexModem program. This will configure your modem to be used with Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Debian, Crunchbangnor other Debian based OS.

You will have to run this program everytime you plug in the modem. To make things simpler, you can put it in /usr/local/bin directory and run it just by typing IntexModem in a terminal.

Note:- You may have to wait 1-2 minutes for your modem to be recognised in Network Manager.

Answer (score 1):

### Step 1

Before plugging in your modem, check the entries in your `/dev` directory.

```
ls /dev
```

You'll find an entry named `sr0` if you have an Optical Disk drive(CD, DVD, Blu-Ray, etc.). If you have no optical drive (as in the case of NetBooks and newer machines), then the dongle's storage will appear as `sr0`, and [IntexModem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245256/how-to-make-intex-3-5g-aka-%E6%99%AE%E5%88%9Be003-wireless-usb-modem-work-on-ubuntu/318434#318434) binary'll work for you. If that's the case, you don't need to follow these steps. Else, plug in your modem, wait a few seconds and then repeat the `ls /dev` command to look again in `/dev` directory.

### Step 2

Inside `/dev` directory, you'll find a new entry `/sr1` along with previous `/sr0`. This is a Read Only partition present on your modem, which must be ejected everytime you plug in the dongle, for switching the modem from removable storage state to modem state.

```
eject /sr1
```

In case you had no optical drive, you'll have to run `eject /sr0` instead. Wait a few seconds and then check your Modem's USB ID:

```
lsusb
```

If everything worked as expected, it'd have turned to `20a6:1105` from the previous ID `20a6:f00e`.

### Step 3

Now you have to load the kernel module to make this device recognised as a USB modem:

```
sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x20a6 product=0x1105
```

Now that you have succesfully loaded the module, the modem will be residing at `/dev/ttyUSB0`, `/dev/ttyUSB1`, `/dev/ttyUSB2`. To check, do:

```
ls /dev | grep ttyUSB
```

If nothing turns out, then wait. It can take anywhere from 30 seconds to a whole minute. Once you are sure there are these ttyUSB entries in your `/dev`, just use your default connection client to connect. For example in Ubuntu, the Network Manager or the connection icon on top panel.

---

### Background/History:

[IntexModem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245256/how-to-make-intex-3-5g-aka-%E6%99%AE%E5%88%9Be003-wireless-usb-modem-work-on-ubuntu/318434#318434) binary didn't work for me and showed strange behaviors such as ejecting the Optical Drive. So I contacted the author of the [IntexModem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245256/how-to-make-intex-3-5g-aka-%E6%99%AE%E5%88%9Be003-wireless-usb-modem-work-on-ubuntu/318434#318434) binary - Prateek "[GunJack](https://askubuntu.com/users/197927/gunjack)" Sharma, who explained to me how the binary works. It's his reply I formulated as this answer.

Newer *usb-modeswitch* versions contain 20a6:1105 and 20a6:f00e config files by default and so you don't need to do the above steps to get it working. As a result, if you're running a recent Ubuntu release, the modem'll work 'out of box' without any extra configuration.

---

*Note*: This question is similar to the AskUbuntu question ["How to make INTEX 3.5G (aka 普创E003) Wireless USB Modem work on Ubuntu?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245256/how-to-make-intex-3-5g-aka-%E6%99%AE%E5%88%9Be003-wireless-usb-modem-work-on-ubuntu/) and [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245256/how-to-make-intex-3-5g-aka-%E6%99%AE%E5%88%9Be003-wireless-usb-modem-work-on-ubuntu/377994#377994) equally applies. I'm reproducing my answer here to ensure a full complete answer exists rather than just a link.